# design incompatibility issue in Firefox15.0.1

Tags: html, css, firefox

[http://www.atticuspetdesign.com](http://www.atticuspetdesign.com/index.php)

this website looks good in google chorme but tis sign  ~ after pet Industry floats to the next line can anybody help me with it i am stuck in this things from last 1 week.:(

its looking like

> [image]

but it suppose to look like

> [image]

Comment: i'm running 15.0.1 and it looks ok to me

Comment: Yup, same for me. Firefox 15.0.1 displays it exactly as Chrome does.

Comment: Browsers have slightly different ways of rendering typefaces, so in Firefox your heading is taking a bit more space which is causing your heading to wrap in two lines. bridgestew's solution fixes the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I can also see the issue in Firefox 15.0.1 on a 15" MacBook Pro.

It doesn't look like you're setting a reset font size (say, 14px).  Setting a default font size on the body and then using em's might help alleviate the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if you have the page zoomed in by accident. That might be what's causing it to look odd.

If you are on a Mac hit CMD + 0 and that should set you at the point of no zoom. Windows might be CTRL + 0, but I'm not sure about that.

I took a look at your code in Firebug. Where you have:

```
.cation-outer {
    margin: 0 0 60px 35px;
}
```

change it to:

```
.cation-outer {
    margin: 0 0 60px 0;
}
```

That makes it look like you are asking for in Firefox. Double check that it still looks how you want in other browsers as well.

Answer (score 0):

I have checked your page on Fireforx 15.0.1 and got the same error.
I think it is because of font size, you can change the width of the container and solve the problem but this is only browser specific solution, this solution mash up the design into chrome. so, I think best solution is to change the font size.

into you `coption-align`  class, apply `font-size: 81px;` to looks the page ok into both chrome and Firefox.

Hope this can solve your problem.